# get previous row calculated column to next row for calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get previous row value to next row for doing calculation but its not working.  Below is my query. Let me explain you what I am trying to achieve. `column Y` is calculating by adding `(n1+n2+n3+n4)/4` of current row and `column x` value will same as `column n1` for first row but from second row and onward `column x` will calculate by adding `column y` of previous row and `column x` of previous row and divided by 2  and so on. Table values can be any

```
CREATE TABLE #TestingData 
(
    nId INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
    n1 DECIMAL(18, 3),
    n2 DECIMAL(18, 3),
    n3 DECIMAL(18, 3),
    n4 DECIMAL(18, 3)
)

INSERT INTO #TestingData 
VALUES (2, 5, 1, 5), (1, 1, 1, 1), (9, 4, 8, 99), (6, 5, 4, 3)

SELECT 
    nId, n1, n2, n3, n4,    
    CASE 
        WHEN nId = 1 THEN x 
        ELSE (MAX(x) OVER (ORDER BY nId) + (SUM(y) OVER (ORDER BY nId) - y)) / 2 
    END AS x,
    y
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         nId, n1, n2, n3, n4,
         CASE 
             WHEN nId = 1 THEN n1 ELSE 0 
         END x,
         (n1 + n2 + n3 + n4) / 4 y
     FROM 
         #TestingData) AS outtab
```

Below is the sample output:

[image]

Comment: What's your expect result from your sample data?

Comment: @D-Shih i attached the sample output

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use cte recursive to make the calculation, by the way you might need to let type more than `DECIMAL(18,3)` otherwise the floating-point numbers will be inaccurate.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT nId,n1,n2,n3,n4,n1 x,(n1+n2+n3+n4)/4 y
  FROM TestingData
  WHERE nId = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.nId,t.n1,t.n2,t.n3,t.n4,CAST((c.x+c.y)/2 AS DECIMAL(18,3)),(t.n1+t.n2+t.n3+t.n4)/4 
  FROM CTE c
  INNER JOIN TestingData t
  ON c.nId +1 = t.nid
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d9fae6e772d5e41e3daacdafe12addbf)

if your `nId` number is discontinuous, you can try to use `LEAD` window function get the next `nId` each rows then do cte recursive

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT *,LEAD(nId) OVER(ORDER BY nId) n_nId,(n1+n2+n3+n4)/4 y
  FROM TestingData
), CTE2 AS (
  SELECT n_nId,n1,n2,n3,n4,n1 x,y
  FROM CTE
  WHERE nId = 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t.n_nId,t.n1,t.n2,t.n3,t.n4,CAST((c.x+c.y)/2 AS DECIMAL(18,6)),t.y
  FROM CTE2 c
  INNER JOIN CTE t
  ON c.n_nId = t.nid
)
SELECT * 
FROM CTE2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=95e09e3c94b2e9d2e63b57fb3fddcdf4)

Comment: output as expected. Would it work efficiently on huge data?

Comment: i try on huge data and it come with error after 40 sec of execution `The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion.`

Comment: The default for OPTION(MAXRECUSION...) is 100. It can be increased as needed, or set to 0 for unlimited